# Issues with Expo ImageManipulator working as expected

Tags: expo

I'm trying to persist a record that has multiple images. Before adding the image I make a call to ImageManipulator to resize the image. The call does return an object but it's never added to the data, not sure why.

Below is a code snippet that shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
    await info.images.forEach(async(image, index) => {
    try {
      const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
        image,
        [{ resize: { width: 640, height: 480 } }],
        { compress: 1, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG }
    );
    console.log("loading the images with",manipResult)
    data.append('image', {
        name: 'image'+index,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        uri:  manipResult.uri
    })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    
  });

  data.append('fac_id', facility.id);
  data.append('sub_sys_type', subsys);
  data.append('condition', info.condition.value);
  data.append('make', info.make);
  data.append('model', info.model);
  data.append('location', info.location);
  data.append('name', info.name);
  data.append('desc', info.desc);
  data.append('sys_type', system);
}
```

As seen above I am logging the manipResult object and is shows as:

loading the images with Object
{
"base64": null,
"height": 480,
"uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImageManipulator/bb228917-fbbb-4acf-bc6f-d33c89d32113.png",
"width": 640,
}

I also log the data object prior to posting it and the image isn't there.

If I don't manipulate the image and add it to the data object it works fine.

I'm new to react native so I need some help with this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance